# Batch file with mysqldump

Tags: mysql, sql, batch-file

I need to backup a database into `.sql` file.
Here's what I'm doing:

```bsh
mysqldump --user=aaa \
          --password=aaa myDb \
          --tables users \
          --where="role_id in(1,3)" > c:\db-backup\users.sql
```

It gives me `all` the records having `role id` = 1 and 3. Is it possible to get only top one row for each role id 1 and 3?

Answer (score 1):

You could probably write a *subquery* in the `WHERE` clause of the form `id IN ( SELECT ... )` (where `id` is your table *primary key*).

I'm not quite sure to understand what you mean by the "top one row", but if for example you need only the rows with the *greatest ID*, something like that might work:

```bsh
mysqldump [...] \
   --where="id IN ( SELECT MAX(id) FROM users WHERE role_id in(1,3) GROUP BY role_id) "
```

Depending your exact need, you probably have to find your own subquery, but I think this is the way to go.